# matches pattern with ArrayList string variable not working

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

here is my code. I store date in dates ArrayList which looks like: [020406,020407...] and   I am searching for pattern in files which is something like that:

```
c001z020102
c002z020103
...
```

Code:

```
private void printReaderContent(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    String line = null;

    for(String tmp : dates) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.matches("[c]{1}[0-9]{3}[z]{1}" + tmp)) {
                xmlCodes.add(line);
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(xmlCodes);
}
```

So I have matches method like in my code and I'm trying to add tmp variable to combine this pattern so I can get selected results from my file. If I use standard pattern like [c]{1}[0-9]{3}[z]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2} it's working, but everytime I put tmp instead i get blank arrayList returned :( I'm using jodaTime to calculate amount of days between and I store it in dates ArrayList:

```
public void countDatesBetween()
{
    int days = Days.daysBetween(dataPierwsza, dataOstatnia).getDays();
    for (int i = 0; i <= days; i++) 
    {
        DateTime d = dataPierwsza.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i);
        dates.add(d.toString("yyMMdd"));            
    }
}
```

I have a file with multiple lines of particular pattern, for example: c001z040206. User puts 2 dates like 2014-06-06 and 2014-06-08 ---> coundDatesBetween creates an arrayList (dates.toString("yyMMdd") which looks like that: [140606, 140607, 140608]. Then I want to search through file with this pattern for c001z which is "[c]{1}[0-9]{3}[z]{1}" and get selected date from tmp which is basically iterating dates ArrayList. So it's should be like that for example: c001z140606 ---> find it in file and return to xmlCodes String ArrayList, but it's just returning blank arraylist.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do or what you're seeing - it would be easier to help you with a [mcve]. (In particular, I can't see what `countDatesBetween` has to do with the rest of the question.)

Comment: Dont put information in comments. Always update your question instead

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the pattern in the `line.matches()` statement. You need to swap inner/outer loop, otherwise you will only try to match the first date.

```
private void printReaderContent(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        for (String tmp : dates) {
            if (line.matches("[c]{1}[0-9]{3}[z]{1}" + tmp)) {
                xmlCodes.add(line);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(xmlCodes);
}
```